# Phone reboots with lldb error

Tags: swift, crash

My app can be installed using xcode and can be used, all functionalities are working. But there's a strange thing happening: when I kill the app from phone or simulator then restart - phone freezes, then reboots after some time.

What I notice is that

- "(lldb)" appears in console,
- phone becomes completely unusable, do not respond to other app launch (e.g. WhatsApp, Maps...). After some time, phone screen turns dark then relaunches.
- I see some Thread 1: signal SIGKILL in AppDelegate class.
- Also, in navigator, there's some "(null)" after program (app) name.
- Memory seems full! 5MB

Please let me know if any code is needed.

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out:

I was killing the app from phone when the app was running and it was connected to Xcode.